# Typewriter JS code keeps getting shorter when repeating and doesn't mantain css colors after first run-through

Tags: javascript, repeat

So I'm fairly newish to coding and I've been staring for hours at this code trying to figure out why:

1. On the first print of the typewriter code it prints it out fine, incorporating all the colors i've added in the css file yet when I call to repeat it, it doesn't - it just prints out plain text.
2. The text being typed out gets shorter by 1 each time it is repeated
3. The more it repeats the more  in the background its printing which is making it get slower and slower to print. I did try .removeChild as I thought this might be why its just adding and adding but I possibly added it in the wrong location

Any help/advice pointing me in the right direction would be amazing.

**HTML**

```
<div class="code-box" id="typecode">
  <pre id="typewriter">
    <span class="var-highlight">let</span> person = {
        name: <span class="string-highlight">'Insert Name'</span>,
        type: <span class="string-highlight">'Insert Type'</span>,
        location: <span class="string-highlight">'Insert Location'</span>,
        
    }; </pre>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.var-highlight {
  color: #c0ad60;
}
.string-highlight {
  color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
}

#typewriter {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  min-width: 45rem;

  &:after {
    content: "|";
    animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
function setupTypewriter(t) {
  var HTML = t.innerHTML;

  t.innerHTML = "";

  var cursorPosition = 0,
    tag = "",
    writingTag = false,
    tagOpen = false,
    typeSpeed = 100,
    tempTypeSpeed = 0;

  var type = function () {
    if (writingTag === true) {
      tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
      tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      if (tagOpen) {
        tagOpen = false;
        writingTag = true;
      } else {
        tag = "";
        tagOpen = true;
        writingTag = true;
        tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
      }
    }
    if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
      tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
      if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      } else {
        tempTypeSpeed = Math.random() * typeSpeed + 50;
      }
      t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
      tempTypeSpeed = Math.random() * typeSpeed + 50;
      writingTag = false;
      if (tagOpen) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        t.appendChild(newSpan);
        newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
        tag = newSpan.firstChild;
      }
    }

    cursorPosition += 1;
    if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
    }

    if (cursorPosition == HTML.length - 1) {  
      setTimeout(restart(), 5000);
    }
  };

  return {
    type: type,
  };
}

let typer = document.getElementById("typewriter");

typewriter = setupTypewriter(typer);

typewriter.type();

function restart() {
  typewriter = setupTypewriter(typer);

  typewriter.type();
}
```

If I remove this, taking out the restart function it works fine for 1 runthrough, but I would like to be able to reset and repeat it once it gets to the end.

```
   if (cursorPosition == HTML.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(restart(), 5000);
    }
```

Maybe I've just been staring at it too long and getting frustrated but I just cannot see how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem with your code was that you're creating a new span every time and "removing" the old one (just adding it as innerHTML), and since your new span never had the original `class` that gave it the color from your `CSS`, then you only had a bunch of spans without class that kept growing with each iteration.

What I did was not adding the old span as a children of the new one you're creating and instead making: `tag = newSpan;`. Then I took the class of the original span and copied it to the `newSpan` you're creating with a regex expression `tag.match(/"(.*?)"/gm` (the expression can be optimized).

So I just modified this part of your code inside the condition `if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === '>') {`:

```
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
let className = tag.match(/"(.*?)"/gm);
if (className) {
  newSpan.classList.add(className[0].replaceAll('"', ''));
}
t.appendChild(newSpan);
tag = newSpan;
```

And you can check the functionality here:

```js
function setupTypewriter(t) {
  var HTML = t.innerHTML;

  t.innerHTML = '';

  var cursorPosition = 0,
    tag = '',
    writingTag = false,
    tagOpen = false,
    typeSpeed = 100,
    tempTypeSpeed = 0;

  var type = function () {
    if (writingTag === true) {
      tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (HTML[cursorPosition] === '<') {
      tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      if (tagOpen) {
        tagOpen = false;
        writingTag = true;
      } else {
        tag = HTML[cursorPosition];
        tagOpen = true;
        writingTag = true;
      }
    }
    if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
      tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
      if (HTML[cursorPosition] === ' ') {
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      } else {
        tempTypeSpeed = Math.random() * typeSpeed + 50;
      }
      t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === '>') {
      tempTypeSpeed = Math.random() * typeSpeed + 50;
      writingTag = false;
      if (tagOpen) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
        let className = tag.match(/"(.*?)"/gm);
        if (className) {
          newSpan.classList.add(className[0].replaceAll('"', ''));
        }

        t.appendChild(newSpan);
        tag = newSpan;
      }
    }

    cursorPosition += 1;
    if (cursorPosition < HTML.length) {
      setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
    }

    if (cursorPosition == HTML.length) {
      setTimeout(restart, 5000);
    }
  };

  return {
    type: type,
  };
}

let typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

typewriter = setupTypewriter(typer);

typewriter.type();

function restart() {
  typewriter = setupTypewriter(typer);

  typewriter.type();
}
```

```css
.var-highlight {
  color: #c0ad60;
}

.string-highlight {
  color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
}

#typewriter {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Courier New";
  min-width: 45rem;
  &:after {
    content: "|";
    animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="code-box" id="typecode">
  <pre id="typewriter">
    <span class="var-highlight">let</span> person = {
        name: <span class="string-highlight">'Insert Name'</span>,
        type: <span class="string-highlight">'Insert Type'</span>,
        location: <span class="string-highlight">'Insert Location'</span>,
    }; 
  </pre>
</div>
```

To avoid losing 1 character after each iteration, you need to modify the length comparison, removing the `- 1` like so:

`(cursorPosition < HTML.length)`
and
`(cursorPosition == HTML.length)`

Comment: That works in regards to allowing the code to keep the css colors, thankyou! However My html.length is still getting shorter with each loop and cutting off 1 character each time. I cannot see where its doing this? I've tried inserting console.log throughout and it loses it as soon as it restarts the code. Any ideas?

Comment: @Eddy That's due to your comparisons of `HTML.length - 1`,  since you're comparing the current position to be lower than the (length - 1), you're basically stopping it 1 character sooner than what you want. For example: `[0,4,8]`  if the current position is `1`, (meaning the 4) it returns true in `(currentPosition < length - 1)`, so you need to remove the ` -1` (I updated my answer)

Comment: Thankyou so much! I had already tried it by changing the -1 to == in the call for the restart but it hadn't worked so I thought I was just being an idiot! Think I must of forgotten to try them both. I actually got it working last night  by adding the last typed part of the }; into a <span> and it doesnt reduce it by 1 each time with that as it'll run through the rest of the code first. Thanks again!!